# Navigation Bar Title Font Size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I need to change the size of the Navigation Bar title text for one view controller in my iPhone app. I'm using iOS5, and tried the following code:

```
if ([self.tabBarItem respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitleTextAttributes:)]) {
    NSLog(@"*** Support method(iOS 5): setTitleTextAttributes:");
    [self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                                [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                [UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                nil]];
}
```

However this only applies to the tabBarItem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to grab the navigation bar property and the use `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes`.

For further info see [UINavigationBar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html) and [Customizing UINavigationBar section](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5).

To understand better your question: What type of controller do you have?

**EDIT**

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:...];
```

if you access the `navigationController` within a pushed controller.

```
[navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:...];
```

if `navigationController` is your current `UINavigationController`. This could be used when for example if you have the following code:

```
UINavigationController* navigationController = ...;
[navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:...];
```

Comment: What if you only want the pushed view to have a different font? I want my root view to have the standard font size, but the pushed view to have a smaller font. I've got it to work with setting the smaller font, but when I go back to the root view, the font remains small when I want it to be the standard size.

Answer (score 25):

You got it already,but you can also use following attributes methods.

**For Color,**

```
NSDictionary *attributes=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor RedColor],UITextAttributeTextColor, nil];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes;
```

**For Size,**

```
NSDictionary *size = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:17.0],UITextAttributeFont, nil];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = size;
```

Thanks.

For iOS 7 and above

**For Size:**

```
NSDictionary *size = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:17.0],NSFontAttributeName, nil];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = size;
```

Comment: I found out it does not work when the font is not properly imported

Answer (score 10):

Since iOS7, I always do like following:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0],NSFontAttributeName,
        nil]];
```

The Keyword `UITextAttributeFont` has been depressed from iOS7, you'd supposed to replace with
`NSFontAttributeName`.

You can use
`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:]`to set someone navigationController's appearence, while `[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:]` works for your whole App directly.(Of course you need to put it in a property position.)

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 2.0:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "DINNextLTW04-Regular", size: 20)!
        ]

        return true
    }
```

Or

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden =  false
  self.title = "SAMPLE"

//Set Color
  let attributes: AnyObject = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
  self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes as? [String : AnyObject]


//Set Font Size
  self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 37.0)!];

 }
```

Comment: the best answer especially this one with appearance() If you need to change all the style

Answer (score 0):

My example

```
guard let sansLightFont = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 20) else { return }
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : sansLightFont]
```