# How to reduce font size of navigation bar title in iOS 7

Tags: ios7

My App has a view controller with a navigation controller on top. The navigation bar title is 'Forgot Password'. This title was shown without any line breaks in iOS 5 and 6. However when I run the same App in iOS 7, the navigation bar title is shown with dots at the end - 'Forgot Passw…'  The only way to rectify this defect is to reduce the for size of the navigation bar title.

Could someone tell me how should I do is ? Is there any APIs in iOS 7 exclusively for this purpose. Is it possible to reduce the font size of navigation bar title for this view controller alone ? Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621455/navigation-bar-title-font-size

Answer (score 7):

```
UILabel *nav_titlelbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationItem.titleView.frame.size.width,40)];
nav_titlelbl.text=@"Tests";

nav_titlelbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

UIFont *lblfont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontinSansCR-Bold" size:20];
[nav_titlelbl setFont:lblfont];
self.navigationItem.titleView=nav_titlelbl;
```

Answer (score 2):

I used following code in my project and its work for me :

```
/* ios 7 Change */
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
    {
        //self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
        //self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x4B678B)];
        NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
        shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
        shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                               [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                               shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                               [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
        // self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        //[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that I am using in my own project(iOS 7)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {       

    // set the title text property, color, font, size and so on
    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
           [UIColor WhiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
           shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
           [UIFont fontWithName:@"your font" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS7, I always do like following:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:SIZE_YOU_LIKE],NSFontAttributeName,
        nil]];
```

The Keyword `UITextAttributeFont` has been depressed from iOS7, you'd supposed to replace with
`NSFontAttributeName`.

Just set `SIZE_YOU_LIKE` a value you like~