# Set font size and center it for Navigation bar title

Tags: ios, swift

I was using an Label before with code like this for the title :

```
     invitationLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    invitationLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    invitationLabel.text =  "GET 10 FREE XXXXX FOR EVERY CONTACT WHO JOINS XXXXXX"
```

I embedded the view controller in nav controller and want the same label.
I am using `self.title=GET 10 FREE XXXXX FOR EVERY CONTACT WHO JOINS XXXXXX`.
But the problem is font size is too big and it is not fitting. So how can I **center the title** and **change its font size**?

Comment: The nav bar title should be short. That's way too much text.

Comment: Size: `label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 20)`. Alignment:
`label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;`

Comment: I think @rmaddy is correct. I should not use so much text for the title. I am going to change it.

Comment: @subodh1989, you can achieve this by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621455/navigation-bar-title-font-size

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a library like [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit).  Then you could set the left and right constraints of your nav bar.  And use the `invitationLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`