# Title in Navigation bar too long

Tags: ios, iphone, navigation

I made an iOS app. On iPhone 6s the title in the navigation bar is "This is my app!". On iPhone 5s the title in the navigation bar is "This is my a…". It's too long. Is there a possibility to autoshrink the text or set an own font size or other header for iPhone 5s?

**Screenshot**
[image: iPhone 6s plus]

I googled nearly all day but could't find any helpfull hint.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation Bar Title Font Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621455/navigation-bar-title-font-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

1. Create a `UILabel`, define its frame, assign text
2. Enable automatic sizing of the text

   ```
   label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
   label.minimumScaleFactor=0.5;
   ```
3. Set label as a titleView of the `navigationItem` of your view controller

   ```
   self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
   ```

Comment: Where to put the code? In ViewController.m under ViewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes, exactly, `viewDidLoad` of your view controller

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "define its frame"?

Comment: I get the error message "Use of undeclared identifier 'label'

Comment: Awesome! By defining frame i meant initializing label with a frame. Looks like you're already doing this, you're using `initWithFrame` to provide frame value.

Comment: Yes, it's working now fine. Now, there's an other problem. I want to make this label clickable for opening an URL in my web view.

Comment: It's working fine with a UIButton but I've an UILabel. It doesn't work with an UILabel. Why that?

Comment: I think I solved this problem, too. I placed an (transparent) UIButton with some spaces over the UILabel. The UIButton is clickable, the UILabel shows the title.

Comment: Awesome man! If you find my answer useful then please accept it. If you encounter more problems create a new question on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, YOUR_WIDH, YOUR_HEIGHT)];
lbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"FONT_NAME" size:FONT_SIZE];
lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.text=@"YOUR TITLE";
self.navigationItem.titleView=lbl;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where to put? In ViewController.m under [super viewDidLoad];?

Comment: Thanks, I did but still no success. I added the code under [super viewDidLoad]; and I replaced YOUR_WIDH=200, YOUR_HEIGHT=30, FONT_NAME=Arial, size:FONT_SIZE=25. I get no error but there's also no title in the navigation bar. Do I have to add a label or something like this?

Comment: Sure. The main question or set as new "answer"?

Comment: Okay, I just did. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Can you help me please? Do I have to do something in ViewController.h? Or create a label?

Comment: This answer wrong. It will not work for long titles. Text will get truncated. Check out my answer